# Continue search after catch Access to the path exception

Tags: c#

This is my function who search for files from given path:

```
static void dirSearch(string dir)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string item in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles(item))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + str);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

why after catch the exception the function stop and not continue and show me the rest of my files from folders with permission ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function stops after catching the exception because the try / catch is outside the loop. Move it into the loop to get the effect that you want:

```
static void dirSearch(string dir)
{
    foreach (string item in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        try
        {
            foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles(item))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + str);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this function is going to search only one level of directories. If you want to search recursively, you need to call `dirSearch` for each directory that you find, like this:

```
static void dirSearch(string dir)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir);
    foreach (string item in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
    {
        try
        {
            dirSearch(item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where i need to put the dirSearch call ?

Comment: Something wrong, the second foreach need to be is other place maybe ?

Comment: @user2214609 Can you see what's wrong? It's a simple copy/paste error. If you can figure it out without looking at my edit, you understood the method.